# transform pose in tf2

Tags: python, ros2, tf2-ros, tf2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 18.04
ROS2 Eloquent (installed by binaries)

I am trying to transform a `PoseStamped` in the target frame in python.

Below would how my code look like:

```
import tf2_geometry_msgs
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
.
.
.
target_pose_s = self.tf_buffer.transform(self.pose_s, target_frame)
```

In this case, I get module not found error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf2_geometry_msgs'
```

I think it is looking for the `tf2_geometry_msgs.py` file, which is not installed for ROS2 on my system. But I can see this for melodic.

```
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.py
```

(it exists in the [eloquent branch](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/eloquent/tf2_geometry_msgs/src/tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.py) though)

In [this issue](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/174), which was addressed in [this PR](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/190) the `setup.py` was said to be "unused". Also [here](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/eloquent/tf2_geometry_msgs/CMakeLists.txt#L31) is marked that Python support doesn't exist yet, though `catkin_python_setup()` shouldn't be needed for ROS2 anymore?

If I comment out `tf2_geometry_msgs`, I get the error

```
tf2_ros.buffer_interface.TypeException: Type <class 'geometry_msgs.msg._pose_stamped.PoseStamped'> if not loaded or supported
```

What am I missing here? Or is it that `transform(PoseStamped, "target_frame")` function not supported yet in Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344028/transform-pose-in-tf2/) by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2020-02-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my understanding the tf2_geometry_msgs are not build for python (the binding) in ros eloquent, you need this pullrequest, and thus move to a more recent ros2 version (i.e master for now): https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/pull/207

---

Originally posted by [lgeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/25222/lgeorge/) with karma: 123 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0